# Crystal Report Loading Error in VS 2010 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I'm doing a project in c# 2010 that generate reports. I want to use Crytal Report for reporting on the project but getting the following error -

**Could not load file or assembly ‘file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet1\crdb_adoplus.dll’ or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

Can anyone help me out this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this error.You have to add following code to your app.config file.

`<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>`

Comment: Read this to know more about the error  http://tektutorialshub.com/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-crdb_adoplus/